# Lisp as a meta environment

Tags: lisp, metaprogramming, environment

I'm working towards my Ph.D regarding better software reuse by integrating different types of computer languages. Due to performance and safety issues I don't consider to integrate them with foreign function calls and/or the use of web services.

Lisp is my favorite vehicle, because of interactive development, macros, doing modifications at runtime, code as data (the usual things one would imagine hearing the word Lisp), and others.
There are some approaches to port different types of Lisp to virtual machines like the JVM (clojure, kawa, SISC, ABCL, etc.) or .NET (clojure .NET, DotLisp, IronLisp). This is quite interesting, but one is restricted to the "universe" of the respective virtual machine.

Does anybody know of approaches the other way round, i.e. running Java or C# on a Lisp system? I have found the rest of cloak. It seem to be more or less a dead project. To me it would be much more sensible to have Lisp as a common abstraction, hosting other languages like Java and C#.

Which obstacles do you see to overcome this lack of a generic and extendable "language environment" integrating languages like Java or C# (without foreign function calls or (web) services))? Is it due to the fact that no Lisp system is running on a kind of a virtual machine, like the LLVM for instance, or what else?

Best regards, Ingmar

Comment: Why would you want to run e.g. C# in a lisp vm?

Comment: if you have actual software related question ask it here. If your question is more general, then use http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ . See the stackoverflow FAQ.

Comment: There's an example of a Forth transcompiler to Common Lisp in Let Over Lambda, and a Python code transformation (transcompiler) to Common Lisp as CLPython. Might be worth your time to check those out, if you haven't already.

Comment: Why one like to run SCALA, Java and Ruby on one platform? Because one needs to integrate these languages for one project. There is no silver bullet, different languages addresses different problems. Moreover, we have trillion lines of code in any language. Why not to reuse them? Instead to reinvent the wheel every some years, it would be more senseful to integrate these programs, which has been partly achieved, but you have to play by the rules of one of the big VMs (Java and .NET).

Comment: VMs are the media for integrating heterogeneous languages runtimes, no singe host language of any given VM can replace them. Otherwise (using, say, SBCL or any other native Lisp), you'll have to handle your FFI and marshalling for each language pair specifically. And, .NET is not that bad - it can handle JVM too (see IKVM).

Answer (score 2):

Lisp is a good platform for this kind of language hosting because of its macro capabilities. However, you want many more language features to do it well: modules, reader macros, high-level macro specification, and so on. [Racket](http://www.racket-lang.org) is one Lisp variant that's going forward in this direction. You can already use [Algol 60](http://docs.racket-lang.org/algol60), a variant of [Prolog](http://docs.racket-lang.org/racklog/index.html), a [typed sister language](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide), and so on. [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) is also moving in this direction with an [ECMAScript](http://wingolog.org/archives/2009/02/22/ecmascript-for-guile) implementation.

As far as implementing Java or C# on Lisp, it is possible in theory but it would require a massive amount of work to support these languages at a practical level (Racket used to implement a small portion of Java). It's also not clear that you would really gain anything considering that the CLR and JVM are both multi-language platforms now. What is more interesting is harnessing Lisp macros to define better custom languages (DSLs), defining useful dialects of your Lisp, or implementing another language specifically to bootstrap a useful tool (e.g., Guile implementing Emacs Lisp).

Answer (score 0):

well "it depends", as always, right?

How much of Lisp do you want expose to Java, if any? For example, if you port the JVM to Lisp, do you somehow mate the JVMs need for a garbage collector to the actual underlying GC of the Lisp implementation, or do you simply write your own that GCs the JVM objects within the JVM heap.

It may very well be impractical to mate the two, for several reasons. The Lisp GC is pretty much hidden, much like Javas GC, from the actual implementation. That may be too hidden to work with a JVM implementation.

There's no reason you can't build a JVM in Lisp, it's just a bunch of byte codes. Lisp handles bytes just fine.

There have been implementations of the JVM in JavaScript, it's not much different than a Lisp at its core.

But beyond having a lispy command line to interact with the JVM, the JVM itself wouldn't be very "lispy". How could it be? It's a JAVA VM. The IMPLEMENTATION can be "lispy", but, ideally, none of that lisp-ness would bubble out to the JVM itself.

Beyond any advantages Lisp has in developing ANY program, I don't think Lisp lends itself specifically to being "better" to developing a virtual machine.

Lisp is great at developing other languages, particularly other S-Exp based languages. But a VM is a VM. Monster case statement or some other dispatch base on numeric values mechanism.

Comment: Lisp is great for developing compilers, and JVM JIT is a compiler indeed. All the things, from simple "nano-passes" with pattern matching, to implementing an SSA-transform, register scheduling and instruction selection are very nice and clean if implemented in Lisp (or, better, on top of DSLs embedded into Lisp). But, of course, this compiler should not be targeting Lisp itself.

Answer (score 0):

Lisp is a perfect host language for such a meta-platform, but it is not necessarily an ideal target language for compiling something low level and imperative. Fortunately, nothing stops you from generating, say, an assembly code within your Lisp environment.

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed languages like C are somewhat uncooperative if it comes to the garbage collector. My demand targets against the causes why there are so less development efforts underway except for the mentioned little and outdated project [cloak](http://lichteblau.blogspot.de/2007/08/cloak.html). I think LLVM would be a very interesting platform for such a language environment, based on Lisp of course. LLVM is much more low level, than JVM and so it should possible to generate bitcode by a Lisp generator.

Comment: @metaman, garbage collection is the smalles of the issues in heterogenous systems. FFI and marshalling are much worse. That's why those "unifying" VMs are so popular. They are limited and limiting, but they are providing a common ABI and common data structures representation for all the languages running on top. LLVM won't easily solve this problem. Btw., thanks for the `cloak` link, it is very interesting.